# Safari/iPhone issue - image outline appearing through radius border

Tags: html, css

Has anyone seen this before?  It's only happening on Safari on iPhone.

Issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffqWz.jpg

Working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1bUB.png

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="round-img round-img-left">
            <img src="assets/img/photo/person2-square.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 advisor-content advisor-content-left">
        <h3 class="heading2 heading-underline">
            Lorem Ipsum
        </h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis iaculis nisi. Duis sagittis id quam ac egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis iaculis nisi. Duis sagittis id quam ac egestas.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.round-img img {
    height: 360px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 35px solid #343434;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The css property border gives this trouble when used along with border-radius. One of the solution I use to get rid of it is use 'box-shadow' property instead of 'border'. Cheers

```
.round-img img {
    height: 360px;
    width: 360px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 35px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 35px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 35px #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 35px;
}
```